# Error 000358 or Error 999999 invalid SQL

Tags: python, arcpy, error-999999, error-000358

i've been searching arround all the answers in the questions of Error 358 and beyond, but i doesn't fix my problems, i tried every post and so on the problems stills there.

I make two options in my code, one make the error 358 appears, and the other option make the error 999999 with invalid SQL. If i put the code "by hand" in the SelectLayerByAttribute_management it works, but i need to be an input by the user. The query its the same by hand and by the script and i dont know how to make it run.

Sorry for the english, not my maternal lenguaje.

The code is:

`Zona_trab=raw_input("Introduzca la ruta de la GDB/carpeta sobre el que se trabajara")
arcpy.env.workspace = Zona_trab 
CapaObj=raw_input("Introduzca el nombre de la capa de tuberias")
CapaArq=raw_input("Introduzca el nombre de la capa de arquetas")
puntos = raw_input("Introduzca las arquetas con datos de permalogs, separadas por espacios: ")
query = ''
first = True
for punto in puntos.split():
    if not first: 
        query = query + 'OR '
    query = query + '\\"FID\\" = ' + punto + ' '
    first = False
query = '" '+query+' "'
TempCarp="C:\\Trabajo Carto\\TempPrograma" 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(CapaObj,"capa tuberias")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(CapaArq, "capa puntos")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("capa puntos","NEW_SELECTION", query)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("capa tuberias", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE","capa puntos","1 Meters", "NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("capa tuberias",TempCarp,"Final.shp","","","")`

The second option, wich give me a error 999999 its deleting the arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("capa puntos","NEW_SELECTION", query) and making the selection in the arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(CapaArq, "capa puntos", query) this makes the error goes in arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("capa tuberias", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE","capa puntos","1 Meters", "NEW_SELECTION").

I hope get some response because i'm stuck in there :(

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE .. What database are you using? Please modify your question to include the Database, version and extensions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround your 999999 error I think something very easy and useful to try will be:

1. Use arcpy.Select_analysis in place of MakeFeatureLayer + SelectByAttribute + FeatureClassToFeatureClass
2. Then just MakeFeatureLayer + SelectByLocation + FeatureClassToFeatureClass on the result of 1

It should simplify the Geoprocessing involved and reduce the amount of memory needed.

Comment: Still the same error, idk if i must ad "" to the numbers, because in other responses some people uses, and other dont

ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "\"FID\" = 3 OR \"FID\" = 5 OR \"FID\" = 6 OR \"FID\" = 8 "
Failed to execute (Select).

And also thanks ^^

Comment: @Gsanez Try this instead `'''"FID" = 3 OR "FID" = 5 OR "FID" = 6 OR "FID" = 8'''`.  If it does not just work then I think you should research/ask about the 000358 error separately from the 999999 error.  It's the latter error that my answer was targeting.

Answer (score 0):

instead of your loop, you could use the "in" operator

```
puntos = raw_input("Introduzca las arquetas con datos de permalogs, separadas por comas: ")#separate with comas
query = """ "FID" in (""" + puntos + """)"""
```

Note that you don't need the \ in your code

`' \\"FID\\" '`  gives \"FID\"

you just need ' "FID" ' or """ "FID" """ or " \"FID\" "

Comment: Thx a lot, with a combo of the two responses it now works. We solve the problem with the 358 whit your "in" and the 999999 wiht the select from the previous response ^^